# Android ImageView setLayoutParams with width bigger than Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

I have ImageView in layout xml like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notePointerImageView"
        android:layout_width="700px"
        android:layout_height="6px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/whiteline"

        />
```

And I dynamically set the width, height, and Margins in onWindowFocusChanged:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams notePointerLayoutLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(263, 2); 
        notePointerLayoutLP.setMargins(0, 150, 14, 0);
        notePointerImageView.setLayoutParams(notePointerLayoutLP);
        notePointerImageView.requestLayout();
```

Since the screen width is only 240x301, the imageView has its left part off screen. But looks like that part of imageView is eliminated and the image is resized inside the screen (I used fitXY), and leaving the ImageView size to be 226x2. (226 + 14 == 240, which is the screen width)

Since I have to animate the ImageView later, I cannot accept ImageView to be clipped and resized. I really need a negative left margin. Could somebody tell me how can I do this? Or is it only a simulator problem?

Comment: put `ImageView` into `FrameLayout`, then set `FrameLayout` layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @Xcihnegn Thanks, I get it to work after wrapping with FrameLayout. The weird thing is that I added FrameLayout, then worked, and I removed FrameLayout, clean and run again, it still works as if the FrameLayout was there.... Anyway, could u please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it. Thx.

Comment: Ok cool! I move it to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force big image to fit inside screen or some size, you can use `FrameLayout` as:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fm_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       ... ...
>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

for fit specific size, you just set the layout size for `FrameLayout`.

Hope this help!